# How to enter safe mode on an HTC Desire w/CyanogenMod stuck in boot loop?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-desire, boot-loop, safe-mode

I have an HTC Desire with CyanogenMod 7 installed. After ignoring the low storage warning for a couple of months, it finally crashed and since then is stuck in the dreaded boot loop. I am able to enter a shell using `adb shell`, and I freed some space (~30M) in the internal memory but to no avail.

After reading about how people solved this problem, a promising way seems to be to enter “safe mode“, then find out which app might cause the boot process to fail and remove it.

I found instructions for the HTC Desire to enter safe mode (turn it on, then keep menu button pressed), but this only let me enter the CyanogenMod recovery menu. My explanation for this is that this behavior is a difference from the stock firmware which most similar question apply to.

I did read the [boot loop tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info), I naturally want to keep my personal data and settings, and factory-resetting the phone is not a desired option.

Comment: Check the logs using "adb logcat" first and try to track down the problematic app or system component. You can also make a nandroid backup first and then delete the culprit's app data ( cf. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data )

Comment: @ce4: sorry for not answering - I checked the logs, but that isn't very expressive. There are no hints about which app is causing the problem. The idea was to use a running system, find out which app I installed last and then delete it. I'm not sure about the nandroid hint, though. I don't have nandroid installed, so there's no way of making a backup.

Comment: Hmm, it might also be /data file system being full and stuck (the htc desire uses the older jffs2 dedicated flash file system). Can you enter the CWM recovery and try do delete some unnecessary data from /data/ (like from a game or so)? It's a bit complicated though (you need some shell/bash skills and the adb android debug bridge tool: "adb shell" and then after you've mounted the /data partition, try to remove some stuff (using the commandline). Else you can fix it by just factory resetting/wiping your HTC Desire if you don't mind losing the app data.

Answer (score 0):

Because I came to this thread from a search, I'd like to share what I found elsewhere:

After powering on the phone, once a logo pops up, press and hold both volume buttons for a very long time.
On my Pixel 6 Pro, I must've held them for about 20 seconds through the initial google logo and then on the progress bar logo, and then the phone vibrated, I let go, it continued to boot for another 10 seconds or so, and ended up in safe mode.  Maybe holding on for longer is necessary if your phone doesn't give you some type of feedback like that.