# Where are WhatsApp messages stored?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Where are WhatsApp messages stored when they arrive? They are stored in backup at 4 AM but before that, where are our latest messages stored? How can we access this location?

Comment: Well, you can't get onto the stored location and all but if you make backup then you can located it over File Manager>WhatsApp>Database folder !

Comment: See: [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924/16575)

Answer (score 1):

/data/data/com.whatsapp/msgstore.db

Comment: Just to confirm, is this the location where the latest WhatsApp messages (as they are received) are stored?

Comment: The parent folder appears to be `/com.whatsapp/databases/` now.