# How can I access the folders where Firefox mobile stores its application data

Tags: firefox-for-android

I know the information is supposed to be at data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/ but I cannot seem to view/access them.

My device is rooted, and I've checked device storage as well as external storage, using multiple file browsers.

Specifically I'm trying to find where it stores the information that it saves for the top sites tab.

Comment: Have you looked at `/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/`? Your profile should be under `/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/`

Comment: Before you ask for the next app, here's a recommended reading: [Where Android apps store data?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924/16575)

Comment: I only asked because, despite it already being said elsewhere, the location given doesn't show the data for me, even though I'm on a rooted device.  The suggestion by Ankush to try accessing from with Firefox itself does work, but that still leaves the mystery as to how I can access those files for editing/etc.

Comment: Can you give is the result of `su -c "ls /data/data/org.mozilla.firefox"` or `su -c "ls -l /data/data/"`? Use a terminal emulator app for that. Also, use @ to notify someone, such as @Izzy.

Comment: I'm positive I'm looking in the correct location.  I've tried ES File Explorer as well as another Root Explorer app.  I've even tried looking through Tasker.  Only one folder is visible inside /data/data/ and it's not for Firefox.

Comment: When running that command using a terminal, it does list the contents of the firefox folder as expected.

Comment: Hmm, then the issue comes back to file explorer apps. Have they been granted the root privileges? What does Superuser app says?

Comment: @vertigoelectric though you're using root *capable* apps, you might have to enable "root mode" for them. I vaguely remember ES had a setting for that (it's quite a while ago I've used it last). Often that's disabled for security reasons (so you don't *accidentally* do something "unlucky").

Comment: I have already considered your suggestion but haven't found a "fix" for it.  I know ES is root capable, but it hasn't asked for permission, it isn't listed in the SuperUser app list, and I'm not sure how to 'force' it to ask.  I'll look into that.

Answer (score 3):

Apps on Android store their data in `/data/data/[package_name]`,
so Firefox should be keeping its data in `/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox`.

**NOTE:** To access this directory you need root access.

Use `file:///data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/` from inside Firefox to access the folder (without root). This work because Firefox owns the folder (see the comments)

Comment: Does `file:///data/data/org.mozilla.firefox` option work without root?

Comment: @SarpSTA, I tested it on FF 40.0, and because Firefox owns the directory, it does work.

Comment: @Firelord Yeah I figured it would. Just the fact that it was given after the notion of requiring root access it kind of confused me.

Comment: I see.  I am able to view the files from inside Firefox as suggested.  However, I need to be able to access these files from outside of Firefox, particularly with Tasker.  My device is rooted, so I'm not sure why I cannot access these files...

Comment: @vertigoelectric Are you using a file explorer that supports root? The default file explorer installed on your device will likely not display any of the `/` (root) directory on your device aside from the internal and external storage. Something basic like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) should do the trick!

Comment: Yes. See comments to my post.