# Where are books downloaded from Amazon Kindle stored?

Tags: ebooks, amazon-kindle

I download a book from Amazon Kindle, and would like to transfer it to my laptop. Where is it stored in my Android 4.4.2 phone (Kyocera Hydro Icon)?

Is it possible to find it out using some download history of Android?

Is it possible to search the file (with guessed file name) in the file systems on my phone using some command or program?

Where is Amazon Kindle app stored? Can the book be stored in the same directory?

Comment: Most likely not (without root). For details, please see [Where Android apps store data?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924/16575)

Answer (score 3):

On my tablet (non-rooted) it exists at

`storage\emulated\0\Android\data\com.amazon.kindle\files\`

Mine has about 500 folders, which, I assume is one per book.
The names are some 10-character string of the form `Bxxxxxxxxx`, where x is alphanumeric. Inside each are a few files devoted to the book, probably the text in the file Bxxxxxxxxx_ebok.prc (it has the largest size), and a couple smaller files tracking reading progress, etc.

I have not been able to determine a translation between the coded folder and file names to the actual book, though I would, if I had tracked my download progress, have a rough idea based on calendar.

Comment: Do you have root access? It's just a guess but it is possible that the app is keeping a map of those hard coded folder/filer names to particular in its database. Lots of apps use database for such things. You can check it out.

Comment: @Firelord - I'm not rooted, and wouldn't have any idea how to investigate this, though I can guess it would involve some SQLite proficiency.

Comment: No proficiency is needed actually. Just an app would do all the job for displaying the data. You just have to search the tables. https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sqlite&utm_source=opensearch