# How do you delete downloaded songs in Spotify?

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to make a Nandroid backup in TWRP but don't have enough space.  I'm pretty sure if I deleted my 500+ downloaded songs there would be enough space.

How do I clear out the Spotify songs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where Android apps store data?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data) See if [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/2o34ph/where_does_spotify_premium_saves_the_downloaded/?ref=share&ref_source=link) helps in your particular case.

Comment: Found the more straight forward "supported" way.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured this one out on my own by poking around in the app.
After following this procedure you will have to login to the Spotify and update any preferences you had previously set.

<sub>*Click images to enlarge*</sub>

1. Turn off "Available Offline" for all playlists you don't want re-downloaded and taking up space on your phone.

   [image: IMG:]
2. Tap the settings/options cog at the bottom right of the sidebar menu.

   [image: IMG:]
3. Scroll to the bottom and tap "Delete cache and saved data".

   [image: IMG:]
4. Tap the OK button.

   [image: IMG:]
5. Wait for the data to clear... Done.

Comment: You can also do it from Settings app.

Comment: I didn't know that you were ready to lose every bit of data of the app, otherwise, I would've suggested the standard method to clear data: Settings -> Apps -> Spotify -> Force stop -> Clear Data. Done. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've sussed how to delete an unwanted track from a downloaded album, click on albums or artists, then at the end of each track click on the dots, you'll see liked click that and it deletes the unwanted track.
Hope this helps.

[image: Led Zeppelin]