# How to access a video file that an app is hiding

Tags: applications, samsung, video

There is this app that uploads some videos. You can watch the purchased ones only through the app! (free videos can be downloaded in pc with IDM)

So I purchased a video and downloaded it so I can watch it offline, and my phone's free space decreased by 1G. I want to copy and save that video on my laptop, but it's not accessible in the phone nor the laptop. Is there any way to find that file?

My phone is a *Galaxy Note 3*. I checked some programs ("Wondershare MobileGo for Android" and "YouWave Android") but they didn't work...

The app is [V – Live Broadcasting App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.naver.vapp). For the other videos I need at least 7G free space!! I was thinking about moving the videos to my laptop so I can download the other 6 episodes :(

Comment: Where those files were downloaded..can you see them in your phone

Comment: Since your free space decreased by 1G,  you might be able to locate the file through [Grid Size](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gridsizefree) (assuming the video is not split into several smaller files). But as Izzy wrote you probably wont be able to watch the video without the app anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you can see it only from within that app: the file will be stored in the app's "private" directory where only itself has access to (unless you use "root powers"). See [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/47951/16575) for details.

Even assumed you'd manage to extract the file (e.g. using root powers) and transfer it to your laptop, you most likely won't be able to watch it: those applications normally use DRM (see [these questions](//android.stackexchange.com/search?q=drm) for details), and their media files are encrypted.

Without knowing the identity of "this app", it's hard (or rather impossible) to say anything more specific.