# Why is application data of the same application stored in different locations?

Tags: applications, internal-storage

I have installed the same application on

- a device running Android 7.0 (**not rooted**) and
- on a tablet running Android 4.4 (**root**),

but nevetheless I noticed that the application data (databases/files etc) is stored in different locations on each device:

On the tablet device the files are located at: `/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.packagename` and can be easily manipulated (i.e copy, back up etc) but not on the smartphone which likely leaves the storage location being: `/data/data/com.packagename` which I have no access to.

---

I understand that it is usually stored on `/data/data` (*protected internal app storage*) or `/storage/sdcard0/Android/data` (*storage on user's internal storage partition*), else on a SD card if present. In addition, a related question has been asked here: [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924/209414)

My biggest surprise is **why is this happening on the same application** (same version - sideloaded)?

This [reference page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location) also explains how a developer can configure the default location of application data. It  would have been  understandable if there were different versions of the application, but here I am only dealing with the same application (i.e `.apk` file). Is there something I am missing here or things have changed in recent versions of Android?

My concern is that I can't access these files on `/data/data` without root and since these are large files and I need to back them up just in case the app data is accidentally cleared (and I have already done that by mistake :(.

Most importantly  I don't want to **continuously download** them over again.

Note: Both devices have **no** external storage attached.

From the look of things the biggest obstacle is not being able to access files on `/data/data`  (device 1), hence no backup possible...(I would appreciate if there is **another reliable workaround to achieve this**)

Comment: Hasn't it always been `/data/data`?  Can you tell what location app data is being stored at? Do you know if the files are data files? Also how do you really know without root?

Comment: I'm certain clear data also wipes data at `/sdcard/Android/data`, in fact I just tried it on a certain app and it did so. Also, I think `/Android/data` and `/data/data` have different purposes. I've found that `/Android/data` is used more for caches/files related to ads whereas `/data/data` is more for private things (eg storing login info).

Comment: @SSS I get your point,but at least on the tablet I can easily back up its data, even if I clear it by mistake it won't have too much harm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As strange as it sounds, I had a successful workaround to this issue:

- I had to manually move the necessary application data (files) from `/data/data` to `/Android/data` (with exception of `shared_preferences` folder and database folder i.e the normal config).
- Second I had configure the app to use a private directory by modifying the `userDefault.xml` file (maybe different depending on application in question) and adding this necessary line of code:

  `<int name="app_private_dir"value_"1"/>`

Comment: I temporarily magisk'd to fully achieved this :)

Answer (score 1):

All apps have private storage in the protracted /data folder. Some apps choose to temporarily store data in public locations. Unfortunately I cannot say for certain what the exact results of this were, but I know the way shared data is handled changed in Android 7 for security reasons.

Comment: so can I possibly back up the app data stored in `/data` folder on this non rooted device