# True full backup of android including profiles

Tags: backup, system

Referring to this tread as an example:[How to make a full backup and restore (including ROM) using Windows PC via USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203556/how-to-make-a-full-backup-and-restore-including-rom-using-windows-pc-via-usb)

I would like to make a full backup, This means everything. Apps files profiles settings literally everything.

there are countless "backup options" some will recover partially some come quite close. (Samsung Smart Switch) But always small issues are missing en old skin and app i use uccw. Settings UI layout etc.
countless small irritating things. The bank app is one of them. While i disagree with the policy of reset when downloading it from the store again, I can see why it is done. Things should be different when i make my own backup.

Summarize is there a way to make a "true backup" from a android phone I have root if that helps.

PS. I can absolutely do without the lecture. My Phone/My Money/My Risk. Just like to know what is possible

Comment: Titanium Backup is the de facto standard for backup of rooted devices... I have never heard of something it doesn't do in this capacity.

Comment: Have you checked with our [backup tag wiki](/tags/backup/info) already? That mostly sums it up. To my knowledge, the only options are TiBu (as mentioned by @acejavelin), and Nandroid. Everything else is far from being complete.

Comment: [Migrate](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3862763)