# Where does Google's Allo store (private) messages and media?

Tags: google, file-system, instant-messaging

I suppose that messages and media sent and received in incognito mode are encrypted but they have to be stored or at least cached somewhere on the device as long as the timer, if any, has not finished. Does anyone know the location/path in the system where Allo stores normal and private messages and media? Is it accessible without root access?

Comment: Please see: [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924/16575)

Comment: Did that. I found the paths '/Allo' and '/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.fireball'. The first contained only a backup file and sent media. The backup does not contain private chats as far as I know. The second directory only contained another empty folder called 'files'.

Comment: And the reral place you could not check as your device isn't rooted: `/data/data/com.google.android.apps.fireball`. Which is where you'd probably find what you're looking for – if you could.

Comment: Note: Google will stop supporting Allo in March 2019