# What is actually occupying the internal storage for the apps, and how to get rid of it?

Tags: internal-storage

I have a Huawei P8 Lite, but this should not be related to the actual device. For a while, the free space on the internal flash just keeps vanishing without installing any new applications. I am storing the media files on the SD card, which is confirmed in the file manager. The file manager says, that my apps take 9.5GB from the internal storage. When I select all the apps in the Google Play application, those take only half of this - not speaking about the fact that most of them is already moved to the SD card (I got that some portion still remains in the internal storage). It can't be the firmware, as that is shown separately in the file manager.

So selectin all apps from which most part is not even there yields only half of the occupied space. What the heck is the mysterious other half? I can't imagine that cache and application-specific data could be that much, as the application widget in the settings is not confirming that.

Is there any app, that actually shows in a spreadsheet all installed apps, the associated storage capacity occupied on each storage device?

Comment: Answered here: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device) and here: [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924/218526)

Comment: @IrfanLatif so you are suggesting, that I either root my phone to see in depth, or save all, make a factory reset, resintall all, and hope for the best?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you have to rely on space usage reported by Android. There is no other way to find out exact space usage details.