# How to identify temporary files by file extension

Tags: cache, temp-files

I want use find command to search and delete all temp files that could exist in android by file extension as a result of device regular usage. So far I could gather the following:

1. `*.tmp`
2. `*.log`
3. all cache folders

etc

But I don't know any other ones can anybody tell me another file extension I could add in my search because I what to run find command while specifying all the file extensions so as to delete them

Comment: There are no standard extensions for temporary files. It's up to apps how they save their files. Also every app's private storage isn't accessible to other apps without root access. So you have to clear cache from app settings. See [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526)

Comment: I have root access and I can search all locations but just don't know what to specify as temp file name so that I can erase all available temp files both for system files too