# Application Images

Tags: google-play-store, files, images

So I am creating this website for an app from Google Play and I am currently trying to find where it's storing the image files on my phone. I've tried to search it with FX file explorer and searched in /data/data and found the app but I'm not sure where to find the images. I know that some apps hide them as another file type so if anyone can help me with trying to get the images, the app is called PC Creator if you would like to try it yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! It would help could you detail what images you are talking about – as the term is quite ambiguous: pictures a) contained in the app, b) downloaded, c) created by the app; d) AppImages in terms of a "bundled backup" of the app and its data; e-z) some [other kind of image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(disambiguation)#Computing). As you didn't link the app, it's hard to see for oneself (you cannot expect potential answerers doing a web-search just to figure what you're asking ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Images are contained in the app

If the images are not downloaded they are contained in the app respectively it's APK file. You can download the APK file from your device (some file explorers allow to do so) or you can download it from an external source like [ApkMirror](https://apkmirror.com), [ApkPure](https://apkpure.com), ...

Once you have downloaded the APK file you can simply unzip the APK file and then manually browser the directory structure or use your favorite file serach to to identify images and other useful files.

If you want to "dig deeper" (e.g. for extracting some string resources or other resources that are not directly accessible as a file within the APK file) you can decompile the APK using a tool like [ApkTool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) (note Apktool is a Java tool and there requires an installed Java-runtime - JRE):

```
apktool d <path to the exported APK file>
```

You will get a directory containing thousands of files, containing the code, XML resources and images contained in the app.

Alternatively you can use a GUI program like [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) (also needs Java, there is a version available that has an integrated JRE, hence does not require to download and install a Java run-time).

Using Jadx you can browse the path `Resources/res/drawable*` to view and save a contained image of the app.

## Images are downloaded

If the images are downloaded while the app is running the are usually stored in the private app-data directory in `/data/data/<app packagename>`.
For more details on this topic see this question: [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data)

To access this directory you need root permissions.

Searching for a specific file on-device especially if the file uses a wrong file extension or a different measure to hide it can be quite tedious. Therefore I would recommend to tar (tar is available on all Android devices by default) the whole directory, export it to a PC and there examine the content:

```
tar cvf /sdcard/app_data.tar /data/data/<app packagename>
```

Afterwards you can download the created tar file via adb (execute the command on your connected PC):

```
adb pull /sdcard/app_data.tar
```

As you are searching for images you may try to directly run `photorec`on the tar file. photorec does not care about file extensions it directly operates on the data, if the image is in a known format and not obfuscated on data level it will be able to find and extract it.

Comment: Apk files can be extracted using a zip explorer. Why would one need to decompile the app just to extract image files? Are they encoded too?

Comment: @IrfanLatif Of course you are absolutely right. Just unzipping is enough. Looks like I decompile Android apps way too often. For me decompiling became the standard for looking into an app.

Comment: As an addendum to your already excellent answer, I'd like to point out that `file` is usually able to guess common file types, as well.

Comment: @Grimoire using `file` or directly reading file signature works only if the app is saving files as normal image files (with or without extension). Carving methods like `photorec` also work if the app is obfuscating files by prepending some unknown signature, or by combining multiple image files to a blob which is recognizable only to the app itself. Data carving works - there are limitations though - even if there is no partition and no filesystem and the data is written directly to raw storage device.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Doesn't carving depend on e.g. magic bytes, or headers and footers being untouched?

Comment: @Grimoire correct. But carving can find out where a standard header begins, even if you prepend something to its beginning (not damaging the original header obviously). `file` utility depends on the existence of a FILE. It looks for signatures at fixed offsets only, won't carve through the whole file looking for signatures/headers. But there are conditions. A major factor is file fragmentation.

Comment: @IrfanLatif You learn something new every day, it seems. Thanks for the info!