# How do I correctly backup android apps with a PC for a factory reset?

Tags: backup

I want to reset my phone. I want to preserve some apps state across the reset. I don't want to use third party software. Which folders do I have to copy?

Comment: Answer to *"Which folders do I have to copy?"*: [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data). On restore you need to set proper UIDs/GIDs, permission modes and SELinux labels on all apps directories. For system and framework apps things are further complicated. Particularly related to content providers. Apps relying on `android_id` may also break after reset. App backup solutions (at least try to) take care of all of this.

Comment: If your device is not rooted you can only use `adb backup`.

Comment: In addition to Robert's suggestion, you can only backup those apps (through adb) which explicitly do not disallow backup (so, bye bye Firefox, Google Authenticator, etc.).

Comment: This question is _not_ about where android stores data and _not_ about fully backup the phone. I want to __backup__ some __decicated__ single apps, like terminus and whatsapp. So it is __not a duplicate__. These suggestions do not answer my question. If it works I guess Roberts comment comes the closest for now, but I had no time to check now.

Comment: [Critical MediaTek rootkit affecting millions of Android devices has been out in the open for months](https://www.xda-developers.com/mediatek-su-rootkit-exploit) depending on your chipset you can try to backup with **mtk-su** https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3922213&page=101