# How to fully back up a phone's content to a PC, possibly for restoring on a similar phone

Tags: backup, restore, broken-screen

I have an LG X-charge phone whose screen is broken, but still functional. I purchased a replacement screen module, but before going ahead on the "open heart surgery", I want to fully back it up. I have another X-charge which is not in use.

I'd like to make a backup on my PC and restore it to the fixed phone, if necessary, or the new phone, if the first one dies.

Can I transfer *all* of the content of the broken phone to the other one? By "all" I mean all media files, messages history, call history, applications, etc. IOW, make a full, restoreable, copy (to whatever extent possible) of the broken phone.

Also, it will be great to be able to access data from the backup (images, messages) on my PC.

Oh, yeah - and preferably, this should be a free solution.

Comment: Have you seen [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](/q/25646/16575) Also, several more helpful links can be found in the recovery section of our [broken-screen tag wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info).

Comment: @Izzy - No, it did not come up in my search. But looking at it, it seems to concentrate on the messages and contacts part. I'd like to have a complete backup that will let me restore either of the phones to the state before attempting the screen fix. The screen itself is not the main point here, but rather the backup, but I'll have a look at the tag you suggested.

Comment: you can `adb pull -a /sdcard` this will at least backup your Internal Storage. MyPhoneExplorer is useful for SMS and contacts. Unfortunately there is no way for complete backup, but you can `adb backup -all` (leave password blank) and restore to other device, this will give you a good base to start figuring out which apps are missing https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224285

Comment: Depending on the point-of-view (and which answer you're looking at), it shows ways to work around the "broken display" – so you can apply solutions as if that restriction would not be there. Like, enabling ADB access (which would need the screen) for `adb backup` (here I'd be careful restoring a "full backup" to another device unless it's the same brand, model and ROM; my tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar/) would a.o. help you to a "modular backup" just in case).

Comment: Update: for lack of time to do the required research and learning of the suggested solutions, I ended up using the `Vysor` application to mirror the phone's screen on my PC and then conveniently taking snapshots of the important SMS histories, and doing simple file copy over USB of my data files.

Answer (score 3):

LG provides different Software (or maybe just different names)
- LG-Bridge
- LG PC Suite
- LG Mobile Switch
- LG ANDROID BACKUP

For experts also there is LGUP flash tool which may shipped with qualcomm factory loader, with this you may able to create/restore full partition dump, root the device without data loss, or install TWRP via [EDL mode](https://github.com/bkerler/edl)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Looking at the LG website, it seems like each one of those provide a partial solution, and I am not sure if any lets you backup your SMSs and MMSs.

Comment: [SMSBackupRestore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) or [MyPhoneExplorer](https://fjsoft.at/en)

Comment: https://github.com/Lekensteyn/lglaf