# Lg G5 sa recovery

Tags: recovery-mode

Love my phone but old, have had it 'die' on me twice now in last 6 weeks. Just got it working after screen showed Fileware upload do not unplug for an hour. I disconnected battery whilst it was plugged in. bingo....working again but what if it dies and I cant get it working. How and where do I back everything up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fully back up a phone's content to a PC, possibly for restoring on a similar phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224356/how-to-fully-back-up-a-phones-content-to-a-pc-possibly-for-restoring-on-a-simi)