# Taking a full backup for LG Velvet 5G (TMO) - does root/su matter?

Tags: root-access, backup

I've got a stock LG Velvet 5G from T-Mobile that I'm turning in for an insurance claim (I was sent an LG V60 in exchange). I'm trying to take a full backup and then wiping it before I mail it out to them.

I've not been keeping up with current events in the tech industry, but upon loading up ADB I'm seeing a deprecation warning, which I've just caught back up about moments ago.  I'm aware ADB backup doesn't necessarily take a full backup (exclusions from manifest, xml paths, etc)., but I'm unsure what other method would be considered more all-inclusive at this point.  Furthermore, upon glancing at the XDA forum for this device ([here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-3-5-0-caymanlm-lm-g900em-unofficial-twrp-for-lg-velvet-5g.4193275/)), it seems that although a method to obtain root is available, the OP declares "backups are broken" and does not further specify any details.  I'm unsure if this means that the best I can do is take the ADB backup and hope it gets everything (and manually backup what I can think of — off the top of my head — that doesn't get captured, like 2FA tokens, etc), but will obtaining root/su actually help or not in my specific situation?

Comment: 1) TMO Velvet is not BL-unlockable and the linked TWRP doesn't apply, and 2) "backups are broken" refers to TWRP's builtin backup capability.

Comment: 2) "backups are broken" refers to the restoring part. you could try [lglaf.py](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224356/how-to-fully-back-up-a-phones-content-to-a-pc-possibly-for-restoring-on-a-simi/224357#comment318315_224357) to by-pass bootloader lock and decrypt with TWRP (untested) but @Robert answer still apply

Answer (score 4):

A rooted device allows to backup data of apps that simply deny backups in their Android manifest.xml.

Root has no effect on Apps that make use of the `AndroidKeystore`. This is a system service that allows to generate and import cryptographic keys (on recent Android devices symmetric and asymmetric keys). Those keys are stored protected by the CPU in  TEE so that apps can make use of the keys but they can't export them. This limitation also applies to backups using root. The keys are bound to the CPU and can't be exported, thus all apps that use such a key to encrypt their app data will fail after restoring their app data  as the necessary key is missing.

Comment: To further elaborate, would a rooted device be able to what you've mentioned in your first sentence above through, say, ADB `backup` with no additional command parameters/flags?  Using, e.g., the `-all` switch?  If not, I'll post a separate question to that regards, thank!

Comment: @Arctiic adb backup always works the same way independently if the device is rooted or not. On a rooted device you can use other backup tools like TitaniumBackup or oandbackupx. But even those tools will fail on apps that use the `AndroidKeystore`. But be aware that you will not recognize that the backup failed unless you recover the app installation from it and try to run the app.