# Where does Swiftkey store its data?

Tags: applications, settings, internal-storage, keyboard, swiftkey

Does anyone know where Swiftkey stores its data for:

1.) the heatmap
2.) user custom word dictionary

Or even better, how would one go about finding this out (on a non-rooted device)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data)

Comment: @Robert isn't Swiftkey a Microsoft Product? I doubt data is only stored locally (at least, idk)

Answer (score 1):

As Swiftkey is a keyboard application and therefore comes in contact with very sensitive user data (credentials, everything you type).

Therefore if you could access such data like heatmap or user custom word dictionary for a different app this would be a vulnerability of Swiftkey. Hence you should not be able to access any data of Swiftkey on a non-rooted device.

Also backup is disallowed for Swiftkey, hence you can't use `adb backup` to export the app data.

Therefore accessing such data is only possible from within the Swiftkey app itself. For example the Heatmap can be viewed and saved within Swiftkey (Keyboard -> three dots -> Settings -> Input -> Input Statistics -> Input heatmap).