# How to clear cache for all apps at once?

Tags: cache

I want to clear all app caches mainly to reduce the size of and speed up backups. [This feature has been supported in Android 4](https://www.androidpolice.com/2012/11/14/android-4-2-tip-you-can-now-clear-all-cached-app-data-at-once/), but appears to have been removed a long time ago.

A root-only method is fine.

Comment: With root: `for cache in /data/user*/*/*/cache/*; do rm -rf "$cache"; done`. For other possible locations see https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526

Comment: @alecxs https://f-droid.org/packages/theredspy15.ltecleanerfoss/ - "Android API 23+ (Marshmallow) no longer allows apps to clean other app’s caches, thus the claim of cleaners clearing them is completely false."

Comment: ...from the Google Play page: "✔ Clear all apps cache at once (1-tap cache cleaner without being root)"

Comment: @alecxs: Root methods are accepted, yes, I was only confused how the app clears caches without root since that doesn't be supported by Android anymore?

Comment: Link2SD requires root permissions for clear cache widget

Comment: [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.at.free) let's you add an widget to clean cache. I have a paid version of app, not sure if it is available in free version or by the same developer, try this [one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.toolbox.full) (developer has all features built in in the first linked app and smaller apps separately)

Comment: I'm considering deleting this question due to potential risks and questionable benefits. [Neo Backup](https://github.com/NeoApplications/Neo-Backup) (formerly OAndBackupX) has an option to exclude app caches.