# I installed a large app & it won't install but takes my storage! now I have full storage but haven't the app?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, installation

I'll be grateful if someone help me! I installed a large app (1.25 G a game) but it won't install because of my low storage it won't install said app not installing just like this; but take my storage! now I have full storage but haven't the app I already cleared the game app and restart my phone but didn't worked...
I use ES filemanager & always check my storages; before installing that app my storage 79% but now 92% I already searched my internal-storage for any tail of the game but it was nothing.
Btw I have to say I did something like this before and it fixed by itself I think after a little time Im not sure  already... ➡My own files pictures, videos ets CAN'T BE 92% its about 600mbs my interal-storage is shown 10.50G & except this I have 2.65Gb installed apps
I have sd card 64G too.
!!!???

Comment: See [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526) and [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526)

Comment: I am not sure if the PackageManager which is responsible for installing apps uses a cache and where it may be located. But the simplest measure but be to install another small app to trigger the PackageManager. May be during the installation process it recognizes that old data from the last install try is still present and deletes or overwrites it.

Comment: It fixed after 3 days by itself again! I think I could only waiting for it to fixed by itself!? anyway thank you very much Robert. :)

Comment: & I think next time I going to buy a new phone as my Android is 7.0 too and cant update anymore so...