# How to find where an app is saving its data and then acess it?

Tags: applications, root-access, 5.0-lollipop

This [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devplank.masterfip&hl=pt_BR&gl=US) provides offline acess to a big database. So it must be somewhere in the device. But i'm having trouble finding where, and if I could even access it when I found it. I can't find the folder `data/data` suggested here [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data) . So I'm guessing that I'll not be able to access it without root ?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. I can only add that even with root permissions you not be able to a case the data as especially valuable offline data is typically saved with extra protection.

Comment: check the other answer */data/user[_de]/<user_id>/<pkg>* means */data/user/0/com.devplank.masterfip* but no access to */data* without root of course (however lollipop is easy to root)