# There's some weird storage nonsense going on, as if part of an app's data is permanent on your phone?

Tags: applications, storage, delete

So, when I want to free up some space, first *yesterday* it said WhatsApp was worth **207MB**, and then *today* it said it was only worth **166MB**, ***What's happening here?!***

Comment: Go in-depth to learn how things work and never get frustrated :) See [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526) and [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526)

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell how you are freeing the storage. If you are using any third party app then it will free the caches of whatsapp. In which case no one can say how much storage is used by your whatsapp cache. Whatsapp it self deletes some caches when there is no need of it. So, if it's cache then it's totally normal.

Other than that you should look into Whatsapp's media folder where all your images,audio,video and docs are stored.