# Remove files left in main storage from failed "Clear Data"

Tags: internal-storage, 7.0-nougat

I used the SnoreLab app for a while and was using the full night audio recording feature.  I started to run out of space on my phone and found that I had accrued 20G of nightly recordings while looking at application footprint in the storage settings view.

When I hit "Clear Data" to free this up my phone chugged for a while and then crashed and rebooted.  Now there is no record that Snorelab is consuming storage, but my phone main memory is still almost full.  I've tried uninstalling Snorelab, which didn't free things up.
I also tried SD Maid and the Drives storage analyzer and Disk Usage.  Both of these show the /data as being >20G but show no folders larger than a few hundred meg.

It seems that there is no record of these files that I have access to but they are still consuming storage on my device.  The device is a Moto G4 running Android 7.

Comment: Check all directories on the "sd-card" section, most likely the app had created the recordings there in an own directory that does not exclusively belong to the app and thus is not deleted on uninstall/clear.

Comment: Everything that's cleared by "Clear Data" is also cleared when you uninstall the app. So the crash didn't leave any garbage. For a broader perspective read [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526) and [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526).

Comment: be aware /sdcard is subdir of /data