# Does work profile installations double the space taken by apps?

Tags: work-profiles

Our EMM configuration installs a separate Chrome instance in the user's work profile.  One user has concerns that this takes unnecessary space from their device.

If the same app (e.g. Chrome) is installed in user-space and inside a work profile, does the installation take double the space, or is the same installation used for both profiles?

Comment: Not exactly. Only data is duplicated, not the executable code. See [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the duplicated app is a system app (e.g., mostly chrome ships as a system app), no double space would be used except for the duplicate app's data.

Incase of third party apps too, most of them doesn't double space in work-profile for app installation (ofcourse except data) but incase the rhird-party app comes with separate graphics or other kind or files stored as obb, some extra space will be taken for installation. (eg games or designing apps)