# Where can an app store a drone video?

Tags: file-system, file-transfer, video, files

I have a Tomzon D65 drone, and the accompanying Tomzon-G app (Ver:1.1.2). The drone captured some awesome footage! It plays in the app fine. However, the app won't let me download the file. I suspect that is because the app was not developed for Android 11.

Regardless, I cannot find the location of this video within the file system. I have tried Android Studio and the Files app from the Play Store. The video is not located in DCMI, Download, Android/Data (com.hy.tomzong), Android/Obb (com.hy.tomzong), nor Movies.

Root/Data gives the message "run-as: package not debuggable." To circumvent this, I tried to create a backup.ab file to view; but, exporting the .ab to a .tar was inscrutable.

In storage, the "space used" lists App as 269MB, and Data as 421MB.

Where can an app hide video files, and how can I retrieve them?

Thanks!,
John

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data)

Comment: Can you play the video without a connection to the drone? If the app supports try to use the "Share-With" menu and upload the video to a cloud drive like GDrive, Dropbox (which is hopefully supported by the app). This should work no matter the app can access the shared storage.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Yes it does! Thanks