# How to access files in Android 6.0 "Downloads"

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, backup, files, download-manager

I have an old Alcatel Pixi 4 with Android 6.0 from which I'd like to back up my files. I've already copied all files from the internal storage except those inside the "Downloads" folder, which actually appears to be an *app* rather than a folder...and it's an utter mess: One can only open downloaded files, but there are absolutely no options to copy, move, rename or even delete anything, so this toxic app basically acts as a trap accumulating any file that has ever been downloaded while completely shutting the owner out.

How can I extract my downloaded files?

Note: The device is not rooted, but I have it hooked up with ADB.

Comment: you probably mean Download History app, should not actually contain any files. nevertheless try ABE extractor. also please check your chipset is qualcomm or MediaTek, should be possible to get root access

Comment: Not sure, I think it's a download manager app that comes with the stock config. I've looked up ABE (https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor), but I'm not sure how it relates to the problem as I never created a backup file. Chipset is indeed MediaTek...so MTKSU? But does rooting solve the problem? If possible, I'd prefer not to root this device

Comment: your assumtion was the files are stored within the app itself? figure out pkgname and have a look into app data. mtk-su is just a temporary exploit it does not root device (not sure if 32 bit arm supported, though). another option to get app data is adb backup (no root required)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507)

Answer (score 0):

```
adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Download C:\platform-tools
```

Comment: If you encounter any errors, try putting both paths in double quotes

Comment: `adb: error: remote object '/storage/emulated/0/Download' does not exist`

Comment: adb shell; echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

Comment: Returns `/sdcard`

Comment: ...there is, however, currently no SD card in the device

Comment: EXTERNAL_STORAGE [/sdcard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7O2M.jpg) is not necessarily external MicroSD Card. *'adb pull -a /sdcard'* and look what's inside (symlinks differ on android version/device)