# How to export data from clouded stepcounter app

Tags: google-drive, export

I am trying to get to the data recorded by a step counter app from Leap Fitness Group:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pedometer.steptracker.calorieburner.stepcounter

I have had this app for a rather long time and I'd like to acquire the data that it has been recording to analyze and visualize it with data analytics software myself. I don't know which file I need to export from the app folder, as all the files seem to have some day in 1981 as their last edit date. The app also syncs to my google (drive?) account, but I can't find the files in my Google Drive. I have searched the internetz for solutions, but my searches have returned zilch, and I don't know how to monitor an app on Android to see where it's writing to and in what format.

If you have ever tried to export your data from an app by Leap Fitness Group, I invite you to share your experiences.

Comment: Related: [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924/218526)

Comment: Unfortunately this app declares `android:allowBackup="false"` in it's manifest and it targets API 30, which means backup is completely disabled. It it does backup data to the cloud this is done in a custom way without help of Android OS. If the app does not provide an export function on it's own. I have seen that it makes use of Google Firebase which also provides a database function. Most likely the data is store there, but the firebase db doesn't belong to your Google account but to the app developer's (they can see all data).

Comment: @Robert unfortunately, I also got no answer from the app devs upon my request. This is rather bad...