# How does WhatsApp's View Once work? Does it take internal storage for showing the photos, or are they directly showing it from the server?

Tags: security, whatsapp-messenger

For WhatsApp's View Once photos, are the photos saved somewhere in the phone's internal storage? Or are they directly shown from WhatsApp's server? As WhatsApp claimed they are not stored in photos or camera rolls, does it mean that they are saved somewhere else in the file manager?

Comment: Very related: [WhatsApp view once video - what is the file location in Android file system?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/251075/44325). In short, they are saved in the internal storage that only WhatsApp app can access (the app's private directory).

Comment: Is it possible for other apps like data recovery app which are available on play store to access it with the permission of manage all file ? My device is upgraded to android 12 @AndrewT.

Comment: No. "Manage all files" is kind of a misnomer because it can only manage *public* files and folders, the same as what the user can see in a file manager app.

Comment: So it not possible for the recovery app without root permission to access these file and if the view once photo is somewhere in storage then it is not accessible to any app present on play store  @Andrew T.

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Comment: Is it possible for apps on playstore to bypass this android security and access it @Andrew T.

Comment: Sorry, you're straying to another topic again. I won't entertain it in this comment thread.