# How does the app SD Maid find leftover files from apps that the user has already uninstalled?

Tags: applications, uninstallation, cleanup

I read on https://techcult.com/how-to-delete-uninstalled-app-data-on-android/:

> The “CorpseFinder” option is specifically there on the SD Maid to find any leftover files from apps that the user has already uninstalled. It will search and display all such files. Either user can choose to delete all of the files, or if they feel they need any specific leftover files, they can individually select the leftover files they want to remove. Overall, SD Maid is a great, safe, and effective option to remove leftover files after uninstalling apps on Android operating system mobile devices.

How does the app [SD Maid](https://sdmaid.darken.eu/) find leftover files from apps that the user has already uninstalled?

Comment: It compares the [standard directories](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526) apps can have with the list of installed applications.

Answer (score 3):

- First, this app has two versions - SD Maid (which is quoted in the link, recognizing by app logo since I have both versions on my device) and SD Maid SE. I can't link them (see next bullet). The former is in maintenance mode only and mainly targets older versions, while the SE versions target newer Android versions.
- Second, both versions are currently [banned](https://twitter.com/d4rken/status/1693739143702974683)
  from Play store due to *Stalkerware policy* (IMO blatantly unfair when the developer has to justify in limited text to a *bot*, without any human interaction)
- Third, the SE version is **open sourced** (unlike the earlier version) . Quoting from [Corpse finder section of the Github](https://github.com/d4rken-org/sdmaid-se/wiki/CorpseFinder#private-app-data), depending on the *filter* you applied (important), it looks for the following places to clear corpse data:

> Sdcard

> Public media

> Public app data

> OBB resources

> Private app data

> Dalvik cache

> App libraries

> App sources

> Private app sources

> Encrypted app resources

Somebody who understands code can interpret better from the Github code or check in [Discord channel](https://discord.com/invite/8Fjy6PTfXu)

**PS**: If you decide to sideload either version of the apps make sure that you disable Google play protect, else it is possible that it may silently uninstall as per [policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2812853?hl=en-GB)

> It may deactivate or remove harmful apps from your device.

> It may reset app permissions to protect your privacy on certain Android versions

This is applicable as long as the ban (second bullet) continues