# Where does termux sqlite db files be stored?

Tags: termux, sqlite

There was other questions like this but no answer for this. Where is the path to find my sqlite files?

I have Xiaomi Redmi 10 android. And with termux installed SQLite and i was going to start learning SQLite but I don't know where does files are stored And how to change it. Thank you.

Comment: [Where do Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526)

Comment: Termux is an app and thus it can not access database files of other apps without root access.

Comment: Do i really need root access? Wow. That's will be a big problem. Anyway tnx