# Where are the user/config files for the game "Ridiculous Fishing"?

Tags: file-system, data-transfer

*Perhaps this question is too specific, but I am also interested in the more general question of where Android stores hidden/system files, especially user data that would be helpful to transfer to another device.*

The specific question is about the game Ridiculous Fishing. It would be nice to be able to transfer my progress to another Android device.

Just plugging the phone into my computer, I can see the following directories, but there are no files in them:

```
/Android/data/com.vlambeer.RidiculousFishing.humble/cache
/Android/obb/com.vlambeer.RidiculousFishing.humble
```

*Device in question is a Samsung Galaxy S9+, running Android 10. But I have also run this game on other devices such as the Google Pixel (Android 9) and had the same problem finding user data files.*

Is there any way to backup or transfer the configuration files for this game?
Are there other locations that can be searched?

Comment: [Where do Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526)

Comment: What Android version is running on your Android device and what on the "another Android device"? Have you tried to extract the data using `adb backup` ?